# How to check if enum case exist under array in swift

Tags: swift

I would like to check if one particular case of enum exist under enum. I have code to use `contains(where:)` but I am wondering if there is any bettery way?

```
public enum Product: Int {
    case tv
    case video
    case product1
    case product2
}
let products: [Product] = [.tv, .product1]
print(products.first!)

let existsProduct = products.contains(where: { item in
    if case .video = item {
        return true
    }
    return false
})
print(existsProduct)
```

Comment: I don't think there is an effective way, to find out it contains an element, you have to iterate through the array. Btw, you can write in short `products.contains { $0 == .video }`

Comment: The fact that the array contains enum values is really irrelevant. It would be the same if you had an array of `Int` or `String` and wanted to see if the array contained a specific value.

Comment: The enum conforms to Equatable so the code can be simplified to `let existsProduct =  products.contains(.video)`

Comment: Note that in your exemple "if case" is not a good idea since it force you to write return true / false. you could have gone simple with a `return item == .video` however @JoakimDanielson solution is the most appropriate.